# Locally Sobolev function and Fourier transform in distributional sense

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

I have a function $V\in W^{1,1}_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^+)$, such that, $V(x,\cdot)\in C^0([0,\infty))$, and: $V(x,0)=u(x)$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$,where $u\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is given, moreover form some $a\in(-1,1)$:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^+}y^a|\nabla V(x,y)|^2\,dx\,dy<\infty, \tag{1}$$
by (1), we have that, for a.e. $y>0$, $\partial_{x_j}V(\cdot,y),\partial_y V(\cdot,y)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n),$ so make sense the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}(\partial_yV(\cdot,y))\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, for a.e. $y>0$. What sense can I give to $\mathcal{F}(V(\cdot,y))$? There is way to prove that $V(\cdot,y)$ is a tempered distribution? In this case, how i can prove that:
$$ \mathcal{F}(\partial_yV(\cdot,y))=\partial_y\mathcal{F}(V(\cdot,y))\tag{2}?$$
Morover, set: $\phi(\xi,y)=\mathcal{F}(V(\cdot,y))(\xi)$, $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n,y>0$, fix $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and set $h(y)=\phi(\xi,|\xi|^{-1}y)$, is true that $h$ is continuos in $[0,\infty)$? How i can show that:
$$ h'(y)=|\xi|^{-1}\partial_y\phi (\xi,|\xi|^{-1}y),$$
and deduce that: $h\in W^{1,1}_\text{loc}(0,\infty)$?
I don't even know where to start. Please, help me.

---

These questions arise from the proof of the lemma 4.1.9 of "Some nonlocal operators and effects  due to nonlocality", by C.Bocur, there is [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.00953.pdf).